# Label elements within a group in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I know how to label elements of one input array like the followings:

```
arr_value = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
arr_res_1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9])  # consider zeros in arr_value as elements
arr_res_2 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6])  # do not consider zeros in arr_value as elements

def shift(arr: np.array, n: int, fill_value=np.nan):
    res = np.empty_like(arr)
    if n > 0:
        res[:n] = fill_value
        res[n:] = arr[:-n]
    elif n < 0:
        res[n:] = fill_value
        res[:n] = arr[-n:]
    else:
        res[:] = arr
    return res

def np_label(arr: np.array, replace_zero: bool = True):
    arr_shift = shift(arr, 1, fill_value=0)
    label = np.where(arr != arr_shift, 1, 0)
    if replace_zero:
        mask_zero = arr == 0
        label[mask_zero] = 0
        label = np.cumsum(label)
        label[mask_zero] = 0
        return label
    else:
        return np.cumsum(label)
```

Now, there are two input arrays including group and value arrays. A label resets on the first element of a new group, it is 0 if the corresponding value is 0, otherwise it starts from 1. How could I do it without spliting arrays or iteration?

```
arr_group = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 3, 4])
arr_value = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1])
arr_res_1 = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1])  # consider zeros in arr_value as elements
arr_res_2 = np.array([0, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1])  # do not consider zeros in arr_value as elements
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find a way to subtract maximum indices of each group before counting `np.cumsum`. `np.add.reduceat` allows you to find these results without a need to split array before. If you pass indices that separates your groups in it, you'll get sum of every group.

```
def refresh_groups(label: np.array, mask_group: np.array):
    mark_idx = np.flatnonzero(mask_group)
    reducer = np.add.reduceat(label, mark_idx)
    label[mark_idx[1:]] -= reducer[:-1]
        
def np_label(arr: np.array, group: np.array, replace_zero: bool = True, replace_group: bool = True):
    arr_shift = shift(arr, 1, fill_value=0)
    label = np.where(arr != arr_shift, 1, 0)
    
    if replace_zero:
        mask_zero = arr == 0
        label[mask_zero] = 0
    if replace_group:
        mask_group = group == 0       
        refresh_groups(label, mask_group)  
        
    label = np.cumsum(label)
    
    if replace_zero:
        label[mask_zero] = 0
    if replace_group:
        label[mask_group] = 0

    return label
    
np_label(arr_value, arr_group, False, False)
```

Just try 4 different options of `replace_zero` and `replace_group` arguments to check if it matches your expected outputs.